# Worldline in very basic TQFT question

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, path-integral, topological-field-theory

Can somebody explain this diagram to me. You have pair production and pair annihilation, and the worldlines of the particles in between the two events. Why are the worldlines a loop, rather than a line?

The only reason I can think of is that the worldlines are probabilistic and the loop is the boundary of a manifold on which the possible worldlines reside. But that's just my random guess.

Edit: maybe another much simpler explanation: there are two pair productions and two pair annihilations, and the loops are the union of the worldlines of a pair.

[image: diagram]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second explanation is correct. Two pair productions and two annihilations, with braiding in the middle.